# how to fix 403 error experienced only when writing to a Google sheet

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am getting a 403 error when accessing the Google spreadsheets API while trying to update the value of a cell. Reading is not a problem. I assume this is a permissions issue

I already went into the API console and the service account was set to the viewer and I have set it to the owner with no results

This works

```
sheet.cell(2,4).value
```

This does not work

```
sheet.update_cell(2,4,"test")
```

> 2019-10-04 13:05:09,560 - https://sheets.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v4/spreadsheets/REDACTED/values/Sheet1%21D2?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE HTTP/1.1" 200 None
>
> 2019-10-04 13:05:09,699 - https://sheets.googleapis.com:443 "PUT /v4/spreadsheets/REDACTED/values/Sheet1%21A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED HTTP/1.1" 403 None

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone It ended up being 2 things:
1) the service account was only given viewing privileges on the actual spreadsheet. Duh.
2) I also had protected ranges that spanned further than they were supposed to which resulted in a 400 error. Also duh.

hope this helps somebody!